# What is an intuitive way of thinking about the limit and limit point of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I understand the definition and difference between the limit and limit point of a sequence.

But can anyone give me an intuitive way to think about this "graphically" for instance what should I picture in mind when I hear limit and limit point of a sequence?

Answer (score 3):

$x$ is the limit of the sequence $x_n$ if $x_n$ eventually stays within any neighbourhood of $x$.

$x$ is a limit point of the sequence $x_n$ if $x_n$ visits any neighbourhood of $x$ infinitely often.

Comment: And any enumeration of the rationals has every real as a limit point.

Comment: Equivalently --- $x$ is the limit if for each neighborhood of $x$ we have $x_n$ in that neighborhood for all but finitely many values of $n;$ and $x$ is a limit point if for each neighborhood of $x$ we have $x_n$ in that neighborhood for infinitely many values of $n.$ So the distinction comes down to "all but finitely many" vs. "infinitely many", with "all but finitely many" being a stronger property than "infinitely many". For example, for infinitely many values of $n$ we have $n$ is even, but it is not true that for all but finitely many values of $n$ we have $n$ is even.